# How to keep all characters start with '#' and remove other characters in pandas | Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

That's my input

[image]

My question is How to remove characters and keep all characters start with '#' using pandas?

Desired ouput look like

[image]

Comment: Friend why dont you try giving us a little sample, of your base_df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) with `regex`.
Explain:

1. `( )` : capture grouping
2. `#` : a `#` char
3. `\w+` : words

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['Ignore #foryou #yolo','Ignore #foryou #yolo #yolo','Ignore #foryou #yolo #yoloIgnore #foryou #yolo #yolo']})
df['text'].str.findall(r'(#\w+)')
```

Output:

```
0                                     [#foryou, #yolo]
1                              [#foryou, #yolo, #yolo]
2    [#foryou, #yolo, #yoloIgnore, #foryou, #yolo, ...
```

Comment: Nice! That worked for my case. Tks i'mahdi